# Codeigniter - condition in a query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My query:

```
$CI->db->select('UserID, Email, Alias, Status, Age');
$CI->db->from('Users');
$CI->db->where('Status', 'Available');
$query = $CI->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
//next comes a function that sends $result to the client app
```

Now, it works, but for the records with Age < 18, I would like to get the Alias field empty, so that this value is not transmitted to the user.

How can I achieve that with a MySQL query?

It could be done of course with a PHP foreach loop, but I would prefer to avoid this due to opeation time cost (MySQL query would be probably way faster).

Comment: $CI->db->where('Age','<' '18');

Comment: you can use multiple where like above example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue using Mysql Condition in SQL:

Query will be Like this:

```
SELECT UserID, Email, IF(Age<18, Alias, "") as Alias, Status, Age FROM Users Where Status='Available';
```

You can implement the Query in CI as Bellow:

```
$CI->db->select('UserID, Email, IF(Age<18, Alias, "") as Alias, Status, Age');
$CI->db->from('Users');
$CI->db->where('Status', 'Available');
$query = $CI->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter it is done like this...

```
$where=array('Age <'=>'18',
                'Status'=>'Available');
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->from('Users');
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
  return $query->result_array();
}
else
return FALSE;
```

Comment: Yes, but this will make choosing all the records that have age above 18. And I need something different: the records with age below 18 should be chosen as well, but just without the Alias field.  The Alias field should be stripped away from them.

Comment: u are saying that u need data which is above and below and 18..??:-/

Answer (score 0):

```
   $CI->db->select('UserID, Email, if(Age < 18) as  Alias, Status, Age');
   $CI->db->from('Users');
   $CI->db->where('Status', 'Available');
   $query = $CI->db->get();
   $result = $query->result();
```

or you can also write query like this:

```
$query=$this->db->query("select UserID, Email,if(Age < 18) as  Alias, Status, Age from users where status='Available'");
```

Comment: I need to strip away the Alias fields only from records with Age <18, and the above code does something different, it chooses only records with Age < 18.

Comment: I'm starting to think of running two separate queries and then combining them together.